# Edit colors xml values on runtime

Tags: android

I have seen similar questions here. I know that we cant edit packaged *.apk files, so we cannot edit `res/values/colors.xml`. However, can we design in a way where we can change the colors (one shot) for the entire application by code or by referring colors.xml from SD card. For example I have colors.xml,

```
<resources>
    <color name="tableBorder">#ff000000</color>
</resources>
```

On runtime I want to get the `tableBorder` color from the local database (or server) and apply so that where ever `tableBorder` is referred, the expected color applies.

Any way to accomplish the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning colors in XML file just store it in SharedPreference files. so that you can change the values runtime whatever you get from server.

Comment: Will I still be able to access the color in layout XML ? Like `@color/tableBorder` or some thing like that ?

Comment: you can not use in Layout XML. but you can change the color runtime.

Comment: Ok. If I use SharedPreference, can I apply the colors for entire application (one shot) ?

Comment: it depends on how you use it. if you want predefined themes then you can set style.xml for themes.

Comment: Yes. But the thing is that the themes are dynamic. I can set parameters of the theme in an XML on server and it is transferred to the device when app starts. Thats when I am setting the colors for the application.

Comment: You can do it only by programmatically. you can't just set in XML file if its the case as you said.

Comment: if its only saving the color codes and image names for your themes then sharedpreference will do it for you.